# Can Non-static function modify a static variable in c++

Tags: c++

can Non-static function modify a static variable in c++

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, a non-static member function can modify a static data member as long as the data member's visibility allows it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see [this example](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html) for a small sample program.

Conversely a static function cannot modify a regular member variable the way a regular member function can.

Comment: You can refer to a static member using the same syntax as a non-static member. You also have the option to use the class_name::static_var syntax.

Comment: Pedantically, a static member function can modify a non-static data member under the same rules as a non-static member function can, *if* it can specify an instance of the class on which to make the modification: `some_instance.some_member = some_value`. It's just that a static member function has no `this`, and unlike a non-static member function, just naming `some_member` doesn't implicitly mean `this->some_member`. So the static member function needs to get an instance from somewhere - a non-static member function has one handy and has a shorthand way of specifying the members of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Think of "static members" as if they were attributes that characterize the class while "non-instance members" characterize instances.

Classes define a concept while instances are occurences of this concepts.
A silly example is the class `Human` is a concept while you, Andy, is an instance. You are one human among 6 billion others.

Human concept says that all humans have limbs, head, eyes and so on. Those are *instance fields*. Every human instance has its own limbs, head, eyes...

I can specialize the human concept according to his/her profession.
Lets consider a `ComputerEngineer` class that defines, obviously, computer engineers.
Any instance of computer engineer *is* a human and still has limbs, head, eyes...

The `ComputerEngineer` class, however, can be modeled so that it has a qualifier (or attribute) that says the minimum salary that the category sindicate allows. Lets call it `minimumWage`

This is a situation were the same attribute must have a common value for all the class instances.

Note that although this `minimumWage` is not an instance member and cannot have different values for each instance, it is still related to the concept, so it is reasonable that it can be accessed.

The following fake code is valid in the sense of having an instance method accessing a static member:

```
class Human
{
protected:
  Limb leftArm;
  Limb leftLeg;
  Limb rightArm;
  Limb rightLeg;
};

class ComputerEngineer : public Human
{
protected:
  static double _minimumWage;
  double _wage;

public:
  wage( double w )  // non-static member function can only be called by instances.
  {
    if ( w < minimumWage )
       throw "You're gonna have trouble with the union!";
    _wage = w;
  }

  minimumWage( double w )
  {  _minimumWage = w; }
};
```

Comment: We don't always need to use the scoped operator to access the static member? I mean, shouldn't it be `ComputerEngineer::_wage = w` instead of just `_wage = w`?